# How to return number of times a base case is reached

Tags: scala

Just started learning functional programming and I'm having problem getting my head wrapped around it. This is what I currently have, I know why it doesn't work (because comb is immutable) but I can't seem to think how to do what I want to.

```
  def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
    def rCountChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int], comb: Int): Int = {
      if (money >= coins(0)) rCountChange(money - coins(0), coins, comb)
      if (money == 0) comb + 1 //base case sequence found
      if (coins.isEmpty) comb //base case sequence not found
      rCountChange(money, coins tail, comb)
    }
    rCountChange(money, coins, 0)

  }
```

I thought of making way an array and just appending to it and .length'ing the result but it seems like its just a gimmicky way of getting around using a mutable var.

If I replace comb + 1 with println("combination found") it prints the right amount of base cases found so I'm pretty sure it's iterating through all the possibilities properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `else`'s at the end of your `if`'s, alternatively you could use `return`.

As it is the function keeps evaluating after it hits the case and doesn't return as you intend it to. In the absence of `return` keyword Scala treats the result of last expression evaluated as part of a function as return value, in your case it's always `rCountChange(money, coins tail, comb)` causing infinite recursion.

Here:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
  def rCountChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int], comb: Int): Int = {
    if (money >= coins(0)) rCountChange(money - coins(0), coins, comb) 
    else if (money == 0) comb + 1 //base case sequence found
    else if (coins.isEmpty) comb //base case sequence not found
    else rCountChange(money, coins tail, comb)
  }
  rCountChange(money, coins, 0)

}
```

Alternatively:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
  def rCountChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int], comb: Int): Int = {
    if (money >= coins(0)) return rCountChange(money - coins(0), coins, comb) 
    if (money == 0) return comb + 1 //base case sequence found
    if (coins.isEmpty) return comb //base case sequence not found
    rCountChange(money, coins tail, comb)
  }
  rCountChange(money, coins, 0)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To give some background, this question is for one of the assignments from Odersky's class on Coursera. I happen to have the solution that passes his tests, and want to give you a hint without giving away the full implementation. As of right now, neither Vlad's nor alex23's answers pass the tests.

The key is to have recurse in two directions: coin-wise and money-wise (you're on the right track), until you run into the base cases. And unless the base case is reached, each case should return the sum of its recurrences, not just one or the other.

Comment: I wasn't aware it's a homework exercise for a popular course, my answer addresses the immediate question. Hope this will help Enders to get unstuck and progress further with his solution.

Comment: Understood - your answer is correct to show author's missing returns where he expects them to.